# Managing element references in javascript projects

Tags: javascript, css

I just spend an hour over a bug that came down to using two different names for an element id.

I would like to know what is best practice to organise those. In Java I would create constants from string literals and refer to those.

I'm using handlebars, so I can inject element names into templates. I would not know how to organise CSS. Ans how to have a central 'repository' of references.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on this subject myself, but I was where you are at a year ago. It was really tough to handle everything. The Javascript/HTML/CSS combo quickly became overwhelming. My best advice is: don't use element IDs. Try to generalize everything into classes. (Working with Bootstrap taught me a lot about how that could be done efficiently.)

And when that's not enough, break your templates into smaller templates. Don't have one large Handlebars template, have 15 small ones. Then use a helper to render them within each other. Breaking your templates into smaller pieces will keep your CSS and JS code in small, cohesive chunks. You'll soon have a CSS file that isn't the CSS file for your page, but the CSS file that contains a different section for each of your templates.

As I said, I'm no expert, but this is what helped me. I came into web development last August with a strong C++ background and this is what finally clicked with me. Basically, it's one of the golden rules of programming: smaller, more modular chunks of code are always easier to deal with. :)